# C++ global object losing values

Tags: c++

I have a class called Player_Sprite. I have declared an instance of it globally like this:

```
Header:
      shared_ptr <Player_Sprite> MainPlayer;

CPP:
      shared_ptr <Player_Sprite> MainPlayer = make_shared<Player_Sprite>();
```

I've tried:

```
Player_Sprite player = (*MainPlayer);
//Do more here
```

I've noticed I will lose values previously set with player.

```
Player.SetState(Moving); //Example
```

Player will lose his state however and still be at Stopped.

However do I refer to this instance of Player_Sprite without using -> that won't just copy it and leave me wondering where my values went?

Comment: Uhm what? The pointer-to-structure member access operator `->` don't copy anything. Can you please elaborate on the actual problem you have? Preferably with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Perhaps you need to debug the program as well? Then you might want to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `shared_ptr` as if it was a normal pointer:

```
MainPlayer->SetState(Moving);
```

That’s how it’s intended to be used.

```
Player_Sprite player = (*MainPlayer);
```

would just dereference the player and make a copy of it. If you change the copy, the original, of course, won’t change.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure entirely how I should go about it. So with pointers I should just refer to them as intended with ->?

Comment: @trevster344 If you want to access their members you normally use `->` yes.

Answer (score 1):

`Player_Sprite player = (*MainPlayer);` will take a value copy of `*MainPlayer`. This accounts for your "losing values".

Use `Player->SetState(Moving);` instead. `std::shared_ptr` has a clever overload for the pointer to member operator `->` which means you can use it as you would for a bare pointer.

It would be even better if you could change your case conventions to something more standard, so you could write the considerably more readable

`player->setState(Moving);`

Comment: Thank you. This has been helpful.